# Mocha throwing errors when testing node.crypto functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, bdd

I am trying to test my password hashing function but I keep on getting failures due to some TypeError error.

I am sure the function works since I tried to call it from some other file and I get the expected result without any error.

Here is the function:

```
    exports.hashPassword = (password) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        crypto.randomBytes(salt_length, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) reject(err);   

          const salt = buf.toString('base64');

          crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, (err, key) => {
            if (err) reject(err);

            const hashedPassword = '{X-PBKDF2}:'+digest+':'+keylenB64+':'+iterationsB64+':'+salt+':'+key.toString('base64');
            resolve(hashedPassword);
          });
        });
      });
    };
```

Here is the test that fails:

```
    describe('users', () => {

      describe('utils', () => {

        it('should hash a password', (done) => {

          const password = 'secret';

          utils.hashPassword('secret')
          .then((hash) => {
            console.log('Hash: '+ hash);
            done();
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            done(err);
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

And this is the 'error':

```
1 failing

1) users utils should hash a password:
   TypeError: size must be a number >= 0
    at Promise (api\paths\users\utils.js:24:12)
    at Object.exports.hashPassword (api\paths\users\utils.js:14:10)
    at Context.it (api\paths\users\utils.test.js:30:13)
```

Has anyone any idea why?

I am using `mocha` with `should` and developing on `node`.

Comment: It is not clear which is the function throwing the Error. Could you clarify?

Comment: Certainly, there's only one function `hashPassword()` which resides in a file called `utils.js`. Now, if you are asking where the error points at `at Promise (api\paths\users\utils.js:24:12)` then this is the first use of crypto `crypto.randomBytes`

Comment: Well i guess you've already checked the size you are passing to crypto.randomBytes to be equal to or greater than 0?

Comment: @pietrovismara Thanks for lending me another pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [pietrovismara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3142367/pietrovismara) that pointed me towards the solution.

The problem was that `salt_length` was a string and not a number. I was printing out the arguments and I could see they were 'correct' but obviously not the right Type (hence TypeError, I guess...)

I keep the argument in a `.env` file and I read them in using the `dotenv` package which obviously read them as simple strings (as it should)... the reason why it was working when I was 'testing' the function from another file was that in that instance I was not using the arguments read from `.env`, I have something like:

`const salt_length = process.env.SALT_LENGTH || 128;`

Mocha was correclty using `.env` values (strings), but when fooling around with the file I was not loading those enviroment variables.

I learned something today, that is I should go home when tired instead of charging on and not seeing things in front of my eyes.

Also, since `mocha` supports promises, the 'correct' test case should be (using `should`):

```
describe('users', () => {

    describe('utils', () => {

      it('should hash a password', () => {
        return utils.hashPassword('secret').should.be.fulfilled();
      });

    });
  });
```

Comment: You could even remove the `.catch()` and let Mocha handle it for you.